# Refreshing an OLAP (pivot table) when login credentials are required

Tags: excel, vba, olap

One of the OLAP cubes I connect to via Excel is a secured OLAP that requires a Login ID and Password to be entered when refreshing.  I know I can use the "Save Password" option in the connection properties but that is not secure as it is stored in the connection in a non-encrypted format.

I want to refresh the pivot via VBA and can read from a text file to grab the ID/Password.  Using the normal:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PT1").PivotCache.refresh
```

Triggers the password entry box to pop up.  Is there a way to trigger the refresh and pass the credentials in the command?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to mark "Save password" in Connection Properties, tab Definition. 
If you, for some reason, do not want to, you need to create new connection every time when you refresh. Use your connection string and pass your credentials.

```
Dim myCn As New Connection
myCn.Open (ConnectionString as String, UserID as String, Password as String)
```

You could copy the connection string from your existing connection.